# Google maps API MarkerManager

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markermanager

I'm sure this question will be downvoted, but...

Is Google Maps MarkerManager still "a thing"? On some of the Google documentation I see it [mentioned](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers?hl=en), and in other parts of I [do not](http://googlemaps.github.io/libraries).

All of the information I can find on this library seems very outdated. It also causes an error if this library is included on the page before the Google Maps API is loaded. Is there a newer recommended method for handling lots of markers the way this library does?

Answer (score 0):

2 years Ago, when I was working on map based project, we used markerclusterer library. It might suit your needs. Here's a simple [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers#markerclusterer)

[some more](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/docs/examples.html) examples

Comment: Thanks, I came across that library as well but unfortunately it's not what I'm looking for. I need the ability to show and hide different marker types at different zoom levels and account for what's in the viewport. It seems like that's exactly what MarkerManager does.

Comment: As far as what i understand from your statement, we did the similar thing in two ways. 1) creating different markercluster objects (with different marker icons) and hiding, showing at different zoom levels. We didn't clubbed them at any stage i.e max zoom was set to 15 for clustering 2) defining custom overlays via kml files and processing them using kmloverlay.js

Comment: Example for using different markercluster object example (jsjunkie says #1) is http://googlemaps.googlermania.com/google_maps_api_v3/en/map_example_marker_clusterer.html